# A little javascript help needed here (easy)

Tags: javascript, html

```
  function addOption(selectbox, val, txt){
  ......
  }

  addOption(list, "Cars", "Cars");
```

I need to add this in front of the text of the function:

```
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

So that there is space coming in before the option text...Never mind what it is for, it is just confusing... I just don't know how to insert it into the js code.

If I do it like this:

```
  addOption(list, "Cars", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars");
```

Then the `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` comes into the text, so it gets displayed for the users.
However I need it to be interpreted as "space"...

If you don't understand let me know...

How can I do this? Quotes, double quotes etc?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
function addOption(selectbox, value, text, cl )
{
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    if (cl==1){ optn.className = "nav_option_main"; }
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
```

Comment: Your basic problem is that you are assigning to `innerText` in `addOption()`, instead of `innerHTML`. Still, assigning to `innerHTML` is not recommended since the option text could contain any kind of evil stuff (think XSS), so `sticking with `innerText`/`textContent` is definitely the Right Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the code of the `addOption` function. Something must be going wrong there, since the following HTML does what you want:

```
<select>
 <option>foo</option>
 <option>&nbsp;bar</option>
</select>
```

**Update:** You’re setting the `option`’s `.text` instead of its `innerHTML` — that’s why the spaces get escaped. Try this:

```
function addOption(selectbox, value, html, cl) {
 var optn = document.createElement('option');
 optn.innerHTML = html;
 optn.value = value;
 if (cl) {
  optn.className = 'nav_option_main';
 };
 selectbox.options.add(optn);
};
```

<strike>In JavaScript, you could use string literal escapes (`\xNN`) to force the string character: `\x20`. That won’t help in your case though.</strike>

Comment: @Camran: See my warning about assigning to `innerHTML`. It is *really* not what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution? Use

```
String.fromCharCode(160)  // char code 160 is nbsp
```

in place of `&nbsp;`. Repeat n times via:

```
// n = 3 in this case
Array(3).join(String.fromCharCode(160));
```

So...

```
function addOption(selectbox, val, text, indent){
  if (typeof indent == "number" && indent > 0)
    var indentStr = Array(indent).join(String.fromCharCode(160));
  else
    var indentStr = "";

  var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
  optn.text = indentStr + txt;
  optn.value = value;
  selectbox.options.add(optn);      
}

addOption(list, "Cars", "Cars", 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you refering to list box (select/option)? You don't need `&nbsp;`, simple white spaces `' '` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `text` to prevent encoding...

```
optn.innerHTML = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Test';
```

Comment: Wont this be "dangerous" like in my Q comment by Tomalek?

Comment: @Camran  No, I don't think you have anything to be worried about there. Not sure what "danger" he's talking about